# How do you build relationship and network in life and work?

Tags: networking

I'm a fresh graduate with no working experience. How can I build such relationships once I enter the workforce?

Answer (score 2):

> How do you build relationship and network in life and work?

I would start with a simple rule that a former CIO gave me way back when.  **Always be nice**.  Even when people are being jerks, try to be nice.  People want to be around nice people.

Here are a couple more guidelines:

1. Be honest when dealing with other people.  No one likes a liar.
2. Also, if you have a sense of humor, people love that too. Use it.
3. Talk to people.  If you're shy by nature, start working on getting yourself out of your shell and join in on conversations around the water cooler.

In short, relax, be yourself, and above all else try to always be nice.  This advice can be applied in and outside of work.